# pass an array to a function in php

Tags: php, function

I have an array that I created by this query:

```
$run=0;
$result = $conn->query("SELECT distinct isbn13 from inventory 
                        WHERE quantity>0 and isbn13 like '978%' limit $run, 20");

while($image = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $isbn[$x] = $image['isbn13'];  
    $x++;
} //end while
```

and I need to pass it into this function:

```
$parsed_xml = ProductId_xml($isbn);
```

I know there is information in the $isbn because I used print_r($isbn); and saw the array.  However, when I do the same in the function (var_dump($searchterm); die;), I get NULL.
Here is part of the function:

```
count=0;

function ProductId_xml($searchTerm) {
    var_dump($searchTerm); die;

    $params = array(
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        'Action' => "GetMatchingProductForId",
        'SellerId' => MERCHANT_ID,
        'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
        'SignatureVersion' => "2",
        'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
        'Version'=> "2011-10-01",
        'MarketplaceId' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
        'IdType' => "ISBN",
    );

    $id=array(explode(',',$searchTerm));

    foreach ($id as $newId)
    {
        $count .= $count +1;    
        $params += array('IdList.Id.'.$count => $newId);
    } //end of foreach
```

How do I get the information into my function?

Comment: $searchterm !== $searchTerm. Variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: Get ready to kick yourself.  var_dump($searchterm) has the "t" in lowercase but you pass it in as $searchTerm.  The next problem you will have is that $searchTerm is already an array and you are trying to explode it.  And I have no idea what $params is supposed to be, but += won't work there.

Comment: @James - YUP kicking myself!!! $params is another array that I am using later in the function.  How should I go about adding to it if += does not work?

Comment: Look at my answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incoming variable `$searchTerm` should be an associative array. You don't need to explode it. You should just be able to access the information by saying `$searchTerm['key']` or by using a foreach loop.

```
foreach ($searchTerm as $key=>$val) { 
    $params['IdList.Id.'.$key] = $val;
} //end of foreach
```

Comment: This looks good, except is there any way to get $key to start at 1 instead of 0?  I need it to look like this: IdList.Id.1.  I know the $key is the array position, so I am not sure if I can change that.  Do I just initialize it as $key=1; before my foreach statement?  Or is impossible to change?

Comment: Yeah when you pull the data out of the database initialize `$x = 1;` before you start the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's variable names are case sensitive, so `$searchterm` and `$searchTerm` are different variables.

Try `var_dump($searchTerm); die;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
function ProductId_xml($searchTerm) {
    var_dump($searchterm); die;
```

**$searchTerm** is different from **$searchterm**. Try with:

```
var_dump($searchTerm); die;
```

It should work